# I can't seem to return a specific value from a list created by a loop of Entry boxes.

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I can't seem to get the function addDetails to return a specific item in list newDetails that is created from appending the inputs from entry boxes I created from a loop. Please help.

```
     import tkinter as tk
     from tkinter import*
     from tkinter import ttk
     import csv

     win = tk.Tk()
     win.title("RFBM Scaffolding Dashboard")
     win.configure(background="grey30")

     newDetails = []
     contactInfo = ["Customer Name", "Home Number", "Mobile Number"] 


     contactInfoFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text ='Contact Information')
     contactInfoFrame.grid(column=0,row=1, columnspan=2)

     for row in range(len(contactInfo)):
         curLabel = contactInfo[row]
         curLabel = ttk.Label(contactInfoFrame, text=contactInfo[row]+":")
         curLabel.grid(column=0, row=(row), sticky=tk.W)

for i in range(len(contactInfo)):
     details = Entry(contactInfoFrame)
     details.grid(row=i, column=1)
     newDetails.append(details)

 def addDetails():
     print(newDetails[1])

  button=Button(win,text="Add Details",command=addDetails).grid(row=12,column=0)


  win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation for the code above.

Comment: What exactly is you're getting, what exactly is you need to get?

Answer (score 1):

`print(newDetails[1])` returns `str` representation of an `Entry` object *as* expected. If one needs to get the input of an `Entry`, [`get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) method can be used instead:

```
def addDetails():
    print(newDetails[1].get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this for getting desired output

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("RFBM Scaffolding Dashboard")
win.configure(background="grey30")

newDetails = []
contactInfo = ["Customer Name", "Home Number", "Mobile Number"] 


contactInfoFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text ='Contact Information')
contactInfoFrame.grid(column=0,row=1, columnspan=2)

for row in range(len(contactInfo)):
    curLabel = contactInfo[row]
    curLabel = ttk.Label(contactInfoFrame, text=contactInfo[row]+":")
    curLabel.grid(column=0, row=(row), sticky=tk.W)

for i in range(len(contactInfo)):
     details = Entry(contactInfoFrame, textvariable = newDetails)
     details.grid(row=i, column=1)
     newDetails.append(details)

def addDetails():
    for i in range(len(newDetails)):
        print(newDetails[i].get())

button=Button(win,text="Add Details",command=addDetails).grid(row=12,column=0)


win.mainloop()
```